# Java Action Listener

Tags: java

Actually, I've got a confusion in Java while implementing action listener event. I can add action listener event by implementing the class with `ActionListener` and by

```
someButton.addActionListener(this);
```

But, I came to know this also does the same thing.

```
someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              //some code...
            }
 });
```

But I could not get it. We cannot use **new** on an interface but it uses it. I get error if I just use try to instantiate the object using **new** only what I expected but it works when I create a block for it using **{}** braces. Could somebody please explain it.

Answer (score 3):

The second construct that you use is called [an anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

It's both a declaration and instantiation of a class at the same time. Although `ActionListener` is an interface, you're creating a new instance of a class that implements that interface along with providing an implementation of its methods (in this case, there's only one method in the interface) and then providing that to the `addActionListener()` method.